# Convert a single row into multiple rows, depending on values in a specific column in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi

I have rows of data which can have information in multiple columns that I need to extract and convert into an individual row for each.

E.g.

[Original table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PRic.png)

Headers are:

**Product Code | Description | Location 1 | Location 2 | Location 3**

and I need to convert it to:

**Product Code | Description | Location**

Some products will be available in multiple regions.

If a product is available in Germany and France, there may be an DE in the Location 1 column, and an FR in the Location 2 column, while the location 3 column will be blank.

I need to convert it so that there is a single location column with corresponding entries for each region that product had.

[Desired output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hk8l1.png)

Is there a way to automate this in Power Bi?

Answer (score 0):

- Select the Code and description columns then

  - UnpivotOtherColumns
- Remove the blank entries
- Remove the Attribute column

Not sure how you want your results sorted, but you could easily add a sorting algorithm to below.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSUfJILAGSLq5AAoRidaKVjICM4OTEojQg7RYElwVJGQMZ7jn5ZanFQEaoN5KC2FgA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Product Code" = _t, Description = _t, #"Location 1" = _t, #"Location 2" = _t, #"Location 3" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Product Code", Int64.Type}, {"Description", type text}, {"Location 1", type text}, {"Location 2", type text}, {"Location 3", type text}}),

//Select Product Code and Description Columns
//  Then "Unpivot other Columns  
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", 
        {"Product Code", "Description"}, "Attribute", "Location"),

//Remove the blank locations and the "Attrubute" column
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", each ([Location] <> "")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Attribute"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]